# Export all WordPress settings except for contents

Tags: wordpress

I need to clone one of my WordPress websites with all databases and plugin settings in order to create a 1/1 copy of the whole theme, backend and functionalities except for contents. I don't want to export posts, pages, media files, comments and every other post type or so, but custom fields, posts database structure etc. 
Are there any plugin to do this?
Or what queries do I have to run via SQL to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've done many similar things, and honestly this would probably be the most time-efficient for you unless you have thousands of posts/pages or something.

1. Install [BackUpWordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/) and create a backup of all your files and the database.
2. Extract the sql file from that archive. Do a search/replace to swap out URLs if the domain name is changing. Then import it into your new database.
3. Upload the entire zip file onto your web server.
4. Extract it.
5. Manually delete all site content from the WordPress backend. Again, unless you have many thousands of posts and pages, this doesn't really take all that long. You can use screen options to display more than 10 or 20 pages/posts at a time for bulk deletion, but I wouldn't recommend going much higher than 100.

That's it! Sometimes brute force is the fastest way. Don't make things more complicated than they have to be.

Comment: I did the same till now but I hope there should be something to exclude content due to The big files size and numbers problems you mentioned

Comment: I suppose it actually might be better to delete the content BEFORE you export. Then the resulting files should be small. But again, if you literally have thousands of pages then I can understand why that wouldn't work.

Comment: So, I hope that backupwp will implement an option to create a backup of everything except for media files and content in future.

Comment: That would be a nice feature! Though now that I'm thinking about it... an FTP backup could do it just as easily. Just download all the folders except uploads, and you should be good to go.